# Adding authors to index from citations

Tags: citing, packages, indexing

I’m writing a book, and using bibtex for references. I’d like to add entries for cited authors to the index, and am wondering if there’s a package or other way to do this automatically. So, if I cite a paper by Jane Smith and John Doe, I’d like “Smith, J.” and “Doe, J.” to appear as two separate entries in the index, along with the page numbers of all papers by them cited in the text. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, almost! Thank you. Is there a way to make authorindex integrate its index with my main index, rather than creating a separate “Author Index”?